# How to get the setTimeout function to run and then stop using a loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am having trouble getting an image to stop moving while using setTimeout method. I have an image that moves a random amount across a page and I want it to stop once it reaches the other image. I tried putting the setTimeout in a while loop, but I cannot get it to work. Below is the code I have in an external javascript file, I invoke the moveCars() function in the HTML:

```
function moveCars() {
    RaceCar1();  
}

function RaceCar1() {
    var finish = document.getElementById('finish');
    var animate;
    var moveCar1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var car1 = document.getElementById('car1');
    car1.style.left = parseInt(car1.style.left) + moveCar1 + 'px'; 
    while(parseInt(car1.style.left) <= parseInt(finish.style.left)) {
    animate = setTimeout(RaceCar1, 500);
    }
}
```

Without the while loop, the image moves across the page forever. But with the while loop in there, the setTimeout only runs once.

*Note: I also tried just setting a value instead of using `finish.style.left` in the loop, but the image still continued to move.

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` (the latter should be called on any event that you want to cause the stop)?

Comment: May be you should use `animate = setInterval(RaceCar1,500)` and then when needed `clearInterval(animate);` or if you insist on using the pseudo recursive `setTimeout()` calls you may place a conditional `return` in your RaceCar1 function before the `animate = setTimeout(RaceCar1, 500);` line

Comment: Please note that setTimeout is asynchronous. This want work with a while loop.

Comment: Don't use setInterval, where possible. requestAnimationFrame is best and setTimeout, if you can't access that, but setInterval doesn't care if previous processing is complete or not, so can cause stack backlogs in fast animation loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code broke my browser, as it created an infinite loop of setTimeout calls due to your while clause. Change that to an if statement and it's fine. You simply wish to re-call your animation routine provided your logic still applies, so you only require an if for that. A while loop will continuously place stack calls to your animation loop repeatedly.

The following code works fine for me:

```
<script>
function moveCars() {
    RaceCar1();  
}

function RaceCar1() {
    var car1 = document.getElementById('car1');
    var finish = document.getElementById('finish');
    var animate;
    var moveCar1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    car1.style.left = parseInt(car1.style.left) + moveCar1 + 'px';
    if (parseInt(car1.style.left) <= parseInt(finish.style.left)) {
        animate = setTimeout(RaceCar1, 500);
    }
}
</script>
<body onload="moveCars();">
    <p id="car1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;">Test</p>
    <p id="finish" style="position:absolute;left:600px;">Finish</p>
</body>
```

If you can use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), use that instead. Would be much better.

Comment: I was using a while statement because I wanted it to continue to loop. But the if statement worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, the if ensures that you loop. When you call setTimeout, you are asking for another loop iteration of the function that it calls. So, it will continue to loop until the logic of the if statement fails. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor like this:

```
function moveCars() {
    RaceCar1();  
}

function RaceCar1() {
    var finish = document.getElementById('finish');
    var animate;
    var moveCar1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var car1 = document.getElementById('car1');
    car1.style.left = parseInt(car1.style.left) + moveCar1 + 'px'; 
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(parseInt(car1.style.left) <= parseInt(finish.style.left)) {
            RaceCar1();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An "if" statement should be enough. setTimeout calls the same function over and over again. Here's a quick example of that

```
var animate;
function RaceCar1() {
    var finish = document.getElementById('finish');
    var moveCar1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var car1 = document.getElementById('car1');
    car1.style.left = parseInt(car1.style.left) + moveCar1 + 'px';
    if (parseInt(car1.style.left) <= parseInt(finish.style.left)) {
        // OPrevent possible errors...
        if (animate) {
            clearTimeout(animate);
        }
        animate = setTimeout(function() { RaceCar1(); }, 500);
    }
}
```

I also set the animate timeout global so that you can cancel unncessary calls to "RaceCar1()".

Finally, I encapsulated "RaceCar1()" in an anonymous function so you get to access the previously declared variable if necessary (for scope sakes)

Hope that helped, this is obviously not tester.